# Jquery .toggleClass() issue

Tags: jquery

My simple jQuery `toggleClass` isn't working. Any help appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".floatRightImage").click(function() {
        $(".floatRightImage").toggleClass(".floatRightImage1");
    });
});
```

This is a very simplified version of it, I've created a fiddle of the simplified version which also isn't working here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8L17wgf/)

Comment: You have a typo inside `toggleClass` function. remove the dot `$(".floatRightImage").toggleClass("floatRightImage1");`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9epthqfr/
I have updated it. Check if this is you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the classname only to toggle it(without `.`). Also you should use it the current element context so use `this`

```
$(this).toggleClass("floatRightImage1"); //Note removed .
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/z0qnhd6s/)

Comment: Wonderful Thank you, I also like that you incorporated the stack image in the demo. I'll make this accepted answer asap.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `this`

```
$(this).toggleClass("floatRightImage1");
```

You can get more info about `this` **[here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this)**

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.` and use `$(this)` as it will refer to the current object. -

```
$(this).toggleClass("floatRightImage1");
```

**Syntax**

```
.toggleClass( className )
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)